# Purpose of "name" and "defaults" in config.Routes.MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In the `global.asax` file, I have something like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

I have another file that has this code:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebConfig
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "DefaultApi",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
                        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835153%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is not very descriptive. What's the purpose of the `name` property? Where else is it used? And same for the `defaults` property: what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` assigns a name to the route by which route can be identified in the list of routes.  This name is used in functions like [`ApiController.Url.Link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944654%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to generate links to route, among others.

`defaults` allows you to provide default values for things such as controller to map request to (if template doesn't specify `{controller}` segment), action to call if not following convention naming nor `{action}` segment in template, default values for parameters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a route can be used to construct rendered links by name. E.g., see [UrlHelper.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492715%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).